# Jquery background mask or multiple background layers

Tags: jquery, background, mask

I am converting a flash site to jquery and the only thing that has me stumped in recreating the footer:
http://www.kevinkubota.com/

Does anyone know a way to recreate this effect. A single image wont do, as the shape background pattern remains fixed as the wave moves left to right. Layering stacking with a mask is a no go, as there are three layers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate this effect using two images.  The background pattern could be a horizontal repeating jpg.  For the waves create two png files, one with semi transparent waves at the top and one with them at the bottom.  The rest of the png files is completely transparent. Create two divs with these files set as the background image and then using jquery to animate them left and right.

Comment: the problem is that there needs to be white areas above and below each respective wave. An area though which the scale bg can not be seen.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your concern.  But if you wrap this in a single div with a specified height, positioned absolutely and overflow set to hidden then the wave portion would be visible within that div and there would be whitespace above and below it.